# Java Hibernate rollback in memory changes

Tags: hibernate, transactions, rollback, in-memory

I use Hibernate to persist my in-memory data. Sometimes Hibernate refuses to commit changes in my objects due to some errors, and executes rollback. In that case my in-memory data becomes inconsistent, and I need it have rolled back either.

My question is: are there any specifications/implementations to help me tracking and undoing in-memory changes. Before trying to write this code myself I want to be sure I'm not going to invent a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back in-memory objects is not possible. But the correct data is in database, so you just need to forget about your in-memory data, and get a fresh copy of them from the database:

1. Get `foo` from database
2. Modify `foo` in memory
3. Try to commit the transaction to update `foo` in database: exception
4. Get `foo` from database again

Comment: Thanks, JB. Your solution is strait-forward, but not so easy to implement, since I do not keep track of all persistent objects in my application.What I'm really looking for is a way to track which changes were made with my objects in which order, and to undo all the changes in reverse order, notifying other software components. I wonder if there are some APIs/implementations to start with.